# Best way to install a service as part of a debian package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, services

I am creating a Debian package for a software application which gets executed from a service script and could like to know the best way to do this.

My current thoughts are for the package to copy the executable to `/usr/bin`, and the service to `/etc/systemd/system/`, and have a `postinst` script to execute

```
systemctl enable myapp.service
```

Is this the correct approach or is there a more 'standard' procedure for handling services within Debian package management?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to package a systemd service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746094/how-to-package-a-systemd-service)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a `.../debian` folder in my projects and create a `.service` file for the daemon. I also add one command line option like so in the `.../debian/rules` file:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with systemd --parallel
```

That option tells the system to use `systemd` to handle the `.service` file (otherwise it falls back on SYS-V).

The one other thing to remember to do is add the `#DEBHELPER#` in your post/pre inst/rm scripts. These are very important since that's what actually makes it all work.

For example, here is a configuration in a `postinst` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "configure" ]
then
     # Turn on IP forwarding
     echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
fi

#DEBHELPER#
```

The position in your script will depend on what you do in your script. i.e. if you want to run a command after the service was started, then place the `#DEBHELPER#` before. If you need to finish up configuration that your service is going to use, then place the `#DEBHELPER#` after that configuration.

I have example in my [Snap! project](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/tree/master).

Note: if you have a project with more than one daemon, you can use the `.../debian` folder trick for one of them. The other, you have to install *by hand* (on your own).